# Why does font size change the size and padding of parent div?

Tags: html, css, margin

I've encountered the following issue. Let's suppose i have something like that in .html file body:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 99%;
  height: 99%;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container1 {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 10%;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.box {
  border: 1px black solid;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}

.box p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container1">
    <div class="box">
      <p>Text 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p>Text 2</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Things i find strange are the following:

1. The size of the yellow boxes stays the way it should until i change the font of 'p' tags inside of those.
2. If i set the margin of 'p' tags to `margin: 0;` the text gets stuck to the top of yellow boxes. Why is it?

How do you increase the size of the font without changing the size of its parent container? And how do you make a custom 'p' tag perfectly centered inside of its parent div?

Comment: are you sure about your height:10% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You set the height as a `percentage`. This will be a problem in smaller sizes. So set its `height` to `px`. Then give the same amount of height to the `<p>` as `line-height`. Also `<p>` has a `margin` by default. You need to zero it here. The following code has been modified.

```css
    html,
    body {
      width: 99%;
      height: 99%;
      margin: 0px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #container1 {
      display: flex;
      gap: 2%;
      width: 90%;
      height: 40px;
      border: 1px black solid;
    }

    .box {
      border: 1px black solid;
      background-color: yellow;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .box p {
      text-align: center;
      margin:0;
      line-height:40px
    }
```

```html
    <body>
      <div id="container1">
        <div class="box">
          <p>Text 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <p>Text 2</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: What if #container1 had `flex-direction: column` and .box had `flex: 1` ? How do i center a text inside of vertically placed yellow boxes?

Comment: Add `align-items:center` to `#container1`

Answer (score 1):

- Just use flex box, min-height

> Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <title></title>
     <style>
html,
body {
  width: 99%;
  height: 99%;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container1 {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2%;
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 10%;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.box {
  border: 1px black solid;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box p {
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
  font-size: 25px;
}
     </style>
 </head>
    <body>
  <div id="container1">
    <div class="box">
      <p>Text 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p>Text 2</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
 </html>
```

- hope this what you want

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

For `p` tag, you can use `top: 50%/left: 50%` in combination with `translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)` to dynamically vertically/horizontally center the element inside its parent.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 99%;
  height: 99%;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container1 {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 10%;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.box {
  border: 1px black solid;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.box p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%); 
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
    
}
```

```html
  <div id="container1">
    <div class="box">
      <p>Text 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p>Text 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```